# How to use a string to control a setVisibility - Android

Tags: android, string, textview, adapter, visibility

I am trying to control a setVisibility in my adapter to get rid of gaps caused by empty TextViews and I am having trouble working out how I would control it using the method I am. 
I tried this and then realised it would not work because there is no View int.

```
date2.setVisibility(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DATE2VIS));
```

How could the Visibility be controlled by the method I am using? Here is the file I am using to give Text to my TextViews via internet.

Online hosted XML file:

```
<games_list>
    <game>
        <id>1</id>
       <title>Grand Theft Auto 5</title>
       <date1>17th September 2013</date1>
       <date2/>
       <date3/>
       <platforms>360, PS3</platforms>
       <thumb_url>
           http://launchpadsoftware.webs.com/ReleaseDates%20Web%20Data/gta5thumb.jpg
       </thumb_url>
    </game>
    <game>
        <id>2</id>
       <title>Grand Theft Auto 5</title>
       <date1>17th September 2013</date1>
       <date2/>
       <date3/>
       <platforms>360, PS3</platforms>
       <thumb_url>
           http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/eminem.png
       </thumb_url>
    </game>
</games_list>
```

This works perfectly for setting the strings required in my adapter but I need the visibility of some TextViews manually controlled via the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a mapping between your data passed and android view visibility properties. What I mean is to make a map like this

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("visible", View.VISIBLE);
map.put("gone", View.GONE);
map.put("invisible", View.INVISIBLE);
```

And pass "visible", "gone" or "invisible" in your XML file. And then use `date2.setVisibility(map.get(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DATE2VIS)))` to set proper visibility.

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense. I will have to try it later and if it works Ill accept your answer.